# How come page isn’t accessible?

Tags: python, django, reactjs, jsx

So what I’m trying to do is make my contact page accessible
when clicked on but I keep on getting an error I don’t know why if everything seems in place also everything seems to imported properly as well.

```
import React from ‘react’;
import logo from ‘./logo.svg’;
import ‘./App.css’;
import Header from ‘./components/header’;
import Footer from './components/footer';
import Home from './components/home';
import About from './components/about';
import Car from './components/car';
import Contact from './components/contact';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import './image-gallery.css';

function App() {
  return (
  <Router>
      <Switch>
             <Route exact path="/">
                {create_page(<Home />)}
             </Route>

             <Route path="/home">
                {create_page(<Home />)}
             </Route>

             <Route path="/about">
                {create_page(<About />)}
              </Route>

              <Route path="/home">
                {create_page(<Home />)}
              </Route>

              <Route path="/car">
                {create_page(<Car />)}

              <Route path="/home">
                {create_page(<Home />)}
              </Route>

              <Route path="/contact">
                {create_page(<Contact />)}
              </Route>
       </Switch>
  </Router>
```

Here is the error that shows up don’t know why if everything seems to be properly put in place and everything imported correctly.

```
> ./src/App.js   Line 43:8:  Parsing error: Expected corresponding JSX
> closing tag for <Route>
> 
>   41 |                 {create_page(<Contact />)}   42 |              
> </Route>
> > 43 |        </Switch>
>      |        ^   44 |   </Router>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing closing JSX tag for "/car"